# How can I get PHP file contents using XHR?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

How can I get PHP file contents using XHR? I get empty response...

```
const promise = new Promise(function (success, error) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
        if (xhr.status === 200) return success(xhr.responseText);
        return error(new Error(`Failed lo load language data. Server response status: ${xhr.status}.`));
    };

    xhr.send();
}.bind(this));
```

PHP file contents that I need to get as text:

```
$_text_block_users = 'Заблокированные ученики';
$_text_id_block_user = 'ID';
$_text_firstname_lastname_block_user = 'Имя, фамилия';
$_text_group_block_user = 'Группа';
$_text_email_block_user = 'Почта';
$_text_contact_person_block_user = 'Контактное лицо';
$_text_telephone_block_user = 'Телефон';
$_text_actions_block_user= 'Действия';
```

HTTP request to PHP file executes it and returns response (empty in my case). I think it is needed to set some HTTP headers.

---

The only solution I found is to use simple AJAX. I call some PHP file, get aim PHP file contents with 'file_get_contents()' function and return this contents to the client side (JS). But I am not pleased with this solution... Hope someone know how to make it in most elegant way.

Comment: Show us your PHP code.

Comment: the js part seems ok so the error must be on the server side. you have to show the php code

Comment: Where is `url` defined? Do you want to literally output the php code or run the php script?

Comment: Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. For modern browsers suggest using `fetch() API` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. It returns promises and has better error handling

Comment: PHP is very simple: there are PHP variables I need to get as text. (Question is updated.) It is OK when I change '.php' extension to the '.txt'.

Comment: I don't see you outputting (echoing) anything in your PHP-file. It only declares a bunch of variables. PHP doesn't magically know what you want to return.

Comment: I don't need echo something in the PHP file. I only want to read PHP file contents using XHR and parse it at client side.(I need PHP file contents as text.)

Comment: put .txt as extension ?

Comment: If you want to read source code of php using TCP you must stop php module from apache (or whatever server). Or change the extension as @MacBooc said of course.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to use simple AJAX. I call some PHP file, get aim PHP file contents with 'file_get_contents()' function and return this contents to the client side (JS). But I am not pleased with this solution... Hope someone know how to make it in most elegant way.